# UIButton not being added to custom UIView Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I am creating a custom UIView called DropDown that contains a button. In the .h file I initialize the button and in the constructor of the UIView, I add it to the frame and set the title. Here is the constructor:

```
 -(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title1:(NSString*)text1{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self){
        _button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_button1 setTitle:text1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _button1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20);
        [self addSubview:_button1];

    }
    return self;
}
```

In my ViewController viewDidLoad I am instantiating a DropDown object as follows:

```
_dropDown = [[DropDown alloc] initWithFrame:_dropDown.frame title1:@"Title"];
```

The _dropDown object is an IBOutlet and I hook it up on the view controller. When I run the application, no button is shown and I am unsure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
_dropDown = [[DropDown alloc] initWithFrame:_dropDown.frame title1:@"Title"];
```

references _dropDown.frame which is `nil` at this point because `_dropDown` hasn't been assigned yet.  I would suggest creating the frame explicitly more like this:

```
_dropDown = [[DropDown alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20) title1:@"Title"];
```

(you'll need to figure out the sizing for `CGRectMake`)